# Is there a way to toggle a Sticker Pack app extension on or off within the main iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully added and ran a Sticker Pack app extension on an app that I have developed in Swift. What I want to do now is have it deactivated from the start and have the user activate it within the app via a button press or in-app purchase.

Has anyone done this at all? I have been searching for a solution for a while and with multiple searches and came up with nothing close to a solution.

Is it just not possible with an app extension and would it have to be done another way?

Answer (score 0):

Either you app has an iMessage extension or not, there is no way to toggle this on and off using the App.